# locahost is not working in Chrome and IE with WAMP

Tags: wamp

I am using WampServer with PHP and MySQL.  When I try to access the localhost I get:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

The weird thing is it works fine in Opera while it does not work on Chrome or Internet Explorer.

Why am I experiencing this issue and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it works for me:

- Click on the Wamp server icon in the Notification area (Taskbar).
- Scroll down and select "Put Online".
- Your server will restart automatically.
- Try to access the localhost again.

Reference from http://en.kioskea.net/faq/28449-wamp-server-error-message-forbidden-you-don-t-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server